# Git warning: unable to access 'P:\/.gitconfig': Invalid argument

Tags: git, git-config

I am just testing git. I ran the following command:

```
git config user.email "test@mail.com"
```

I now get this when `git status` and others:

```
C:\gitg\g1>git status
warning: unable to access 'P:\/.gitconfig': Invalid argument
warning: unable to access 'P:\/.gitconfig': Invalid argument
warning: unable to access 'P:\/.gitconfig': Invalid argument
# On branch master
warning: unable to access 'P:\/.gitconfig': Invalid argument
nothing to commit, working directory clean

C:\gitg\g1>
```

Comment: Does the file `P:\.gitconfig` exist? If so please post the content.

Comment: What does your `$HOME` variable contain? I think the `\/` is strange and likely a problem...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I just encountered this error.
Executing `set HOMEPATH` in the command line gave this output:

```
HOMEPATH=\
```

Simply deleting this environment variable via `set HOMEPATH=` fixed the problem.

Comment: Deleting them from a dos box has no effect, unless you are running git commands directly on the command line inside that dos box

Comment: Restarting your git GUI should help as well as it should pull in the new environment variables in that case.

Comment: This answer (and all of the other path answers) did not work for me.  Disconnecting the network drive it was looking for did.

Comment: and/or you may need to set the HOMEDRIVE environment variable.

Comment: This didn't help because it wasn't permanent. Everytime I opened up the console anew and typed it again it was set again.

Answer (score 17):

I experienced a similar issue when not connected to my work network via VPN.  Deleting the all the HOME% variables did not work.  Deleting the network drive it was trying to access did work. Running the following from a command window worked for me:

net use H: /delete

As a note, I did delete the HOME% variables, but it did work until the command above was run.

Comment: The home variables are a red herring

Comment: This happened to me - my P drive was a personal drive at work. At home I got the error - disconnecting the drive fixed it - thanks !

Comment: This fixed it for me!  I simply disconnected the drive using the GUI.

Comment: This was the problem. Instead of deleting the drive I just connected the VPN and I didn't change any variables :D

Comment: Does deleting the network drive cause any negative side effects when I'm connected back to my work VPN again?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using "Git Bash" (MINGW64) on Windows:

Enter:

```
export HOME=/c
```

To verify:

```
echo $HOME
```

Answer (score 9):

I hit on this and had to set HOMEDRIVE to something sane.

e.g.

```
set HOMEDRIVE=D:
```

Comment: This one worked for me. I guess if the drive you work on is a virtual drive you will encounter this.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing this issue when loading a solution in Visual Studio 2017 (v15.1) running as an Administrator. And my local git repo was located in C:\Code\

To work around the problem,

1. I added an Environment Variable (under User variable) HOME with value C:\
2. Restarted Visual Studio (again as an admin) - this time Git was able to load successfully loading my branch & source control association correctly.

Comment: Where do you add that Environment Variable exactly? Is it through visual studio?

Comment: This works. All the other solutions that set HOMEDRIVE= or Remove-Item Env:\HOMEPATH cannot work because they only set the environmental variable in the context of that console. This answer should be marked as correct.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but with SourceTree. This was the only thing that worked for me. I've tried a lot of things.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

Try running as Administrator. For whatever reason it defaults to a mapped drive.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me to clear the HOME Variable "nearly" to Daniels solution:

```
set HOME=
```

To recheck you have to echo it like this:

```
echo %HOME%
```

Comment: echo %HOME% just outputs "%HOME%" at my PC

Answer (score 3):

For me, I have seen this error in sourcetree, it was just a matter of disconnecting the drive P in my computer as it was a net drive.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this error message intermittently.

The cause was a VPN connection that I used occasionally. It was blocking access to my networked HOMEDRIVE every time I used it; and git could no longer access the config file.

Clearly not the cause here because you found your solution, but I thought I'd add it here for anyone else searching.

Comment: I also just experienced this due to my corporate VPN, however running git bash as administrator works around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error for sourceTree. Setting the HOME environment variable with value C:\ fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on windows 10.

My source code is in C:\workspace and I added an environment variable **HOME to C:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the PowerShell users out there:

```
Remove-Item Env:\HOMEPATH
```

*Thank you @Daniel Hilgarth for the answer*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @daniel-hilgrath, your answer helped me till an extent, it did solve for that particular session.

But in my case I was using SourceTree and on Windows 7. I had to wipe out the Environment variables completely, not only for particular session. I did following.

```
SETX HOMEPATH ""
SETX HOMEDRIVE ""
```

may be this could be useful for someone who is using this on SourceTree.

Comment: Is it HOMEDIRVE or HOMEDRIVE?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**
On Windows 10, I had similar issue with H:\.gitconfig file. Trying to access the file was failing. Trying to delete the file was giving Error 0x800710FE.

**Searching Error 0x800710FE** found this explanation.

Windows 10 sometimes shows weird errors and 0x800710FE is one that appears when you delete a file or folder. Basically, it is a native Office File Synchronization issue that occurs in Win 10, though not enabled by default.

**Solution**
Disconnecting network drive (H:) and trying to connect to git worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that, before trying all the abovementioned methods such as
delete H drive, remove home path etc. Since I found someone was mentioning about VPN and I realized that I was working on my company's laptop and it did have a VPN.

So I fixed my problem by simply disconnected and re-connected the VPN and everything started working.

It makes sense because that I know I did not change anything and it was working yesterday, but stopped working today, so it might be related to the VPN was not successfully launched today, so this led to the thought that I probably should re-start the VPN connection. Which is way much easier and safer and should be tried first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- delete the `.gitconfig` file at the remote drive (H or P)location
- do a `git init` at any location you choose - this will add the configs to `.git` folder at the location (example D:\yourCode.git)
  The above steps helped me to resolve the issue I faced.